# Change method / algorithm Windows uses to scale desktop wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, scaling, desktop-customization

Note: I'm not asking how to use the various options for windows wallpaper fitting (Fill vs. Fit vs. Center etc).

What I want is to change the method windows uses to shrink an image, when you choose one of these options. Because the method it uses sucks. It's something like the difference between bilinear interpolation vs. bicubic.

If you use actual photographs for your wallpaper, and let windows shrink them, they become horribly noisy and crappy looking. See the example below at full size.

[image: Example]

A workaround is to shrink the image in photoshop and then save a wallpaper-sized version. But I have many photos and I'd rather just make windows work the way I want. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Photoshop, you could use
[ImageMagick](http://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick.tool)

```
convert -resize 1920 infile.png outfile.png
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/33ad0c0fd835/misc/musicbrainz.sh#L98)

Comment: well, appreciate the thought, but was hoping there's a registry trick, or a replacement DLL, or something that will force windows to scale intelligently. I could do a photoshop action on the whole folder and save wallpaper-sized ones... but it will produce a few gigs of extra images.